# Does sp_BlitzIndex uses Query Store data?

Tags: sql-server, index-maintenance, sp-blitzindex

SQL Server 2019

1. When running `sp_BlitzIndex` does the result generated is using Query Store data?
   Trying to understand if Query Store affects `sp_BlitzIndex` report.
2. `sp_BlitzIndex` has multiple suggestions in its report,
   I'm trying to understand what steps should follow `sp_BlitzIndex` to verify the need for such an index.
   Should it follow both or one of these two? `sp_BlitzCache`/`sp_BlitzQueryStore`
   An example would be the usage of one of the rows -
   `603 uses; Impact: 100.0%; Avg query cost: 74.4459`
   On paper that looks great, before I copy&paste the TSql of the index, How can I understand which queries exactly would have used the suggested index? (so-called 603 uses).

Kind a lost myself during the index tuning as it feels like every command just redirects to another, not sure where I should stop and act haha.

Ty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### backwards

If anything, you should use sp_BlitzIndex to further validate missing index requests you find while looking for queries to tune to find overall potential uses for the index. The real value of sp_BlitzIndex for me is finding indexes that I can clean up. The missing index section may serve to take the temperature of a database to see if anyone is paying attention to things, but...

The only way to know what real value the request has is to run the query asking for it, get the actual execution plan, and see if the missing index request aligns with a bottleneck there.

I wrote about this a bit here:

- [What Do Missing Index Requests Really Mean In SQL Server?](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/what-do-missing-index-requests-really-mean-in-sql-server/)

Your workflow might be better off as:

- Use other scripts to find queries to tune
- Make note of any missing index requests
- See if the request is "high value" in sp_BlitzIndex
- Test the query with and without the index suggestion

Answer (score 4):

No - the source code for sp_blitzindex does not reference query store DMVs.
Feel free to CTRL/CMD+F through the code here - no mention of query_store dmvs.

https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzIndex.sql